# Javascript function that toggles text of different buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to javascript and web development. I'm building a page that has multiple areas for users to add and save text in. Each text area has a Button with different ID that I use to toggle the text areas between readonly and editable and the text of the buttons "Save" when the text area is editable and "Edit" when the text is read only.

The function below works for 1 button (the editNameBtn). My question is is there is a way to write one function that I can pass the ID of each button to to toggle the text? Rather than having a different function for each button w' different id.

```
function toggleText(editNameBtn) {

 var el = document.getElementById("editNameBtn").textContent;

  if (el == "Edit"){
    el = "Save";
  } else {
    el = "Edit";
  }
  document.getElementById("editNameBtn").textContent = el;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function toggleText(editNameBtn) {
 var el = document.getElementById("editNameBtn").textContent;
  if (el == "Edit"){
    el = "Save";
  } else {
    el = "Edit";
  }
  document.getElementById("editNameBtn").textContent = el;
}
```

In the above functions in getElementById you are passing editNameBtn as string but it is an argumrnt. Please remove the quotes. The below snipet address the isuee

```js
 function toggleText(editNameBtn) {
 var el = document.getElementById(editNameBtn).textContent;
  if (el == "Edit"){
    el = "Save";
  } else {
    el = "Edit";
  }
  document.getElementById(editNameBtn).textContent = el;
  
}
```

```html
<button id="PASSIDHERE" onclick="toggleText('PASSIDHERE')">Edit</button>
<!-- single qutoes in toggleText('PASSIDHERE') and the argument should be same as id -->
```

Comment: Thanks! I also didn't know I had to have the single quotes when passing the  ID <!-- single qutoes in toggleText('PASSIDHERE') and the argument should be same as id -->

Answer (score 4):

You were **close**. You need to pass the parameter of the function as is rather than wrapping it with double quotes.

change

```
var el = document.getElementById("editNameBtn").textContent;
```

to

```
var el = document.getElementById(editNameBtn).textContent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass in the ID of the button to your function, as a string.

```
function toggleText(buttonID) {
    var el = document.getElementById(buttonID).textContent;

    if (el == "Edit") {
        el = "Save";
    } else {
        el = "Edit";
    }

    document.getElementById(buttonID).textContent = el;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be updated like this.

```
function toggleText(btnId) {

 var el = document.getElementById(btnId).innerHTML;


  if (el == "Edit"){
    el = "Save";
  } else {
    el = "Edit";
  }
  document.getElementById(btnId).innerHTML= el;
}
```

**And**

Your Html should be like this

```
<button id='editNameBtn' onclick='toggleText("editNameBtn")'>Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function toggleText(btn_id) {
 var el = document.getElementById(""+btn_id).textContent;
  if (el == "Edit"){
    el = "Save";
  } else {
    el = "Edit";
  }
  document.getElementById(""+btn_id).textContent = el;
}
```

```js
function toggleText(btn_id) {
 var el = document.getElementById(""+btn_id).textContent;
  if (el == "Edit"){
    el = "Save";
  } else {
    el = "Edit";
  }
  document.getElementById(""+btn_id).textContent = el;
}
```

```html
<button id="id1" onclick="toggleText('id1')">Edit</button>
```